# Site collection problem after migration and reinstalling and and reattach content db

Tags: migration, iis, project-server, restart

we had a problem on our developing farm that force to re-install MS-project-server.

After running Configuration Wizard and reconfigure content-DB of SharePoint and reconfigure it install msps again and then create PWA. SharePoint and Project server is ok and the test is ok.

the problem appears after restart Server or IIS or everyday startup when calling http://server for example the white page appear without any prompt or correlation error.

but when we open in browser http://server/pwa everything return to healthy status. and a normal status.

I think the problem for application start on IIS that first site collection cant starts app pool (or cant start session start). but second (PWA) can do it.

extended web applications are ok.

PWA is ok. but only when restart IIS in the first request by browser open white page. and users force to call PWA URL

What is your suggestion and/or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Adding warm up scripts would be a good option. Also, you check the status of application pool using a PowerShell script, If the status of the app pool is in stopped state, you can start it automatically using power shell.

You can schedule it using Windows task scheduler when a server starts the scheduled event runs which automate the process instead of a manual process.

- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-script-to-find-0c4895c9
- https://spbestwarmup.codeplex.com/